# Can't configure trac to work with Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, cgi, trac, mod-fastcgi

I've been trying to set up trac to be deployed with apache for a little while now and I'm running into a wall.

This is the response I'm receiving from my server

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at ***.***.***.*** Port 80
```

This is my apache v-host file: (Comments removed)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /home/***/public_html/app/public
        Alias /trac/chrome/common /home/***/trac/htdocs/common
        Alias /trac/chrome/site /home/***/trac/htdocs/common
        ScriptAlias /trac /home/***/trac/cgi-bin/trac.fcgi/

        DefaultInitEnv TRAC_ENV /home/***/trac

        <Location "/trac">
                SetEnv TRAC_ENV_PARENT_DIR "home/***/"
        </Location>

        <Directory "/home/***/trac/htdocs">
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Location "/trac/chrome/common">
                SetHandler none
        </Location>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /home/***/public_html/app/log/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog /home/***/public_html/app/log/access.log combined


        CustomLog /home/casey/public_html/app/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my server's error log:

```
[Fri Apr 29 02:09:06 2011] [warn] [client **.**.**.**] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Fri Apr 29 02:09:06 2011] [error] [client **.**.**.**] Premature end of script headers: trac.fcgi
[Fri Apr 29 02:09:06 2011] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client **.**.**.**] Zlib: Compressed 618 to 384 : URL /trac/
[Fri Apr 29 02:09:08 2011] [warn] [client **.**.**.**] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Fri Apr 29 02:09:08 2011] [error] [client **.**.**.**] Premature end of script headers: trac.fcgi
[Fri Apr 29 02:09:08 2011] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client **.**.**.**] Zlib: Compressed 618 to 384 : URL /trac/
```

Does anyone know what might be going on and what I should do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not precisely sure, If I get this all right. I assume that you have installed trac in a directory via trac-admin. For me (I'm not using fcgi), the following location directive works in several cases

```
<Location /mytrac>
       SetHandler mod_python
       PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
       PythonPath "sys.path + ['/usr/share/trac']"
       PythonOption TracEnv /var/trac/mytrac/wiki
       PythonOption TracUriRoot /mytrac
       AddCharset utf-8 .css .html .xhtml .py
</Location
```

Try this in you default vhost.conf to check, if it works for you.